# Apache Reverse Proxy doesn't forward request headers?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have set up a reverse proxy in my Apache 2.4 virtual host configuration file. However, the additional headers such as API_KEY that get added by the authentication system are not being passed on to the server. How do I get Apache to include these headers? I have been able to find NO documentation on this...

This is the proxy line:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:8999/var/www/production/public/$1
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out? It's pretty obvious in nginx. But I agree, not really documented in apache.